# Android streaming MSMPEG-4 V3 Video

Tags: java, android, video, stream

I have a camera, that streams application/x-mplayer2 type video, format : MSMPEG-4 V3 Video. When I try to open stream with android, it trows an error : "Sorry, this video cannot be played.". I try to stream with this:

```
private void playVideo() {
            try {
                final String path = "http://82.140.132.217:8001";
                System.out.println("path --> "+path);
                Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
                if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                    if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                        mVideoView.start();
                        mVideoView.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }
                    current = path;
                    System.out.println("Current path --> "+path);
                    mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();

                    System.out.println("end try in play");

                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I stream this type of video? Or is there any way to convert video stream to another type?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`application/x-mplayer2` is not a video format , here is the list **http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html** of video formats and streams supported by android.
Once you knew actual format and stream type of your camera , if it is not in compatible format you can use [FFMPEG](https://github.com/tito/ffmpeg-android) to convert that stream.

Comment: edited question. Format: MSMPEG-4 V3 Video . Can I still convert it somehow?

Comment: I don't want to frighten you but Video Streaming with unsupported files in android is not a straight forward thing. You have to know many thing i.e Video Format, Stream type(RTSP, RTMP) Video Packet(Mostly they are RTP). You have to be acquainted with full specification of your Stream type and Stream method(M3U8), Video File size being broadcasted from your camera.

Comment: What is your target version device ? below 3.0 There is no support of M3U8 in android.

Comment: Target device api : 2.2 . Is there any way to convert, that I would be able to stream it from my device ( gingerbread 2.3 )

Comment: first of all extract a test streamm file from your camera. and than try to convert its format using ffmpeg desktop version using desktop binries of ffmpeg http://ffmpeg.org/download.html if u are successfully able to convert it than you can use this method https://github.com/tito/ffmpeg-android to compile ffmpeg for android.

Comment: batter use Unix type os .. other wise you have to messup with compilation of ffmpeg for android to. because it is too an complex process

Comment: Yeah. So I downloaded it, and what options do I need to use? Is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: yes there are many tutorial you can google it. you have to do much R&D